# Find the exact Build Number of a specific Mac OS X update from the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, build-version

How do I find the System Build Number or I guess it is called just the Build Number (example 18A391 or  18G87 or 18G5033 or etc. etc.) for a specific Mac OS X updates? Not upgrade, just the regular updates. Examples: Supplemental or Security or Combo or Safari, etc. etc.

I am aware of thousands of blogs and websites that published those type of informations, but let's do a practical example:

**Step #1**
I download this specific dmg file (Security Update 2020-006 (Mojave)) from: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2062?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

**Step #2**
I mount the dmg file and I extract the pkg file.

Now, I do believe that the pkg file that I just extracted from the dmg file it is some sort of xar archive file, so my question is:

using the **command line**, how do I unzip the xar archive file and after I unzip the archive, **what specific plist file** I am looking for in order to find out the exact Build Number of this specific Security Update 2020-006 update?

Thank you

Comment: Seems you have the tasks nicely identifed (unxar the xar archive, take the plist, look up the build numer), what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm curious, what problem are you really trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant file for that specific dmg is `SecUpd2020-006Mojave.pkg/PackageInfo`.

After mounting the dmg, do this:

```
% cd /tmp
% xar -x -f /Volumes/Security\ Update\ 2020-006/SecUpd2020-006Mojave.pkg SecUpd2020-006Mojave.pkg/PackageInfo
% grep -o 'com.apple.pkg.update.*" ' SecUpd2020-006Mojave.pkg/PackageInfo | sed 's/.*\.//'
```

For updates that have been automatically downloaded to `/Library/Updates/`, the relevant file is named `*.dist`. For instance, in `001-48382/001-48382.English.dist` there is

```
<key>macOSProductBuildVersion</key>
<string>17G14033</string>
```

and also

```
com.apple.pkg.SecUpd2020-005HighSierra.RecoveryHDUpdate.17G14033
```